# GnuPlot chart drawing for each text file

Tags: charts, text-files, gnuplot

I compare four kind of sorting algorithms, and their inversions and comparisions for each algorithm are stored in a file. What I need now is to draw a scatter with markers `(x,y)` **for each file** where

```
x -> number of inversions
y -> number of comparisions
```

and scale it to the numbers, so for example we have `IS10.txt` which stands for `InsertionSort` and it has 300 lines with x's and y's.

**Sample data**

```
line 1: 20 33
line 2: 18 27
...
line 300: 21 24
```

The key is to be able to generate diagrams for comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Plotting a single file is straightforward, just use

```
plot 'IS10.txt' using 1:2 title 'InsertionSort'
```

If you want to plot all files, you can do it as follows:

```
list = system('ls -1 *.txt | tr "\n" " "')
set key out
plot for [file in list] file using 1:2 title file
```

Here, I assumed, that all `.txt` files in the current directory should be plotted. You could of course also generate the `list` manually. It should contain all file names, delimited by a space (e.g. `list = "IS10.txt HS10.txt ..."`).

That plots all data points of one file with the same `linetype`. The first file uses `linetype 1`, the second one `linetype 2` etc. Type `test` to see how the points and colors of these default `linetype` look like.

You can use something like `set linetype 1 linecolor rgb 'blue' pointtype 7` to change these settings in order to get `20` well-distinguishable point styles.

Comment: Hey. I assume that GNUPlot is a stand-alone software, and can not be connected directly with my Java program. Am I assuming correctly?

Also, could you please tell me what this tr "\n" " " exactly stands for?

Comment: @user2095534 Yes its a standalone program, but you can call it from Java like any other external program, and also pipe data to it. The call `tr "\n" " "` replaces a newline with a space, see `man tr`. But I've seen, that this is not necessary, so having `list = system('ls -1 *.txt')` would also do.

Comment: OK, we're clear on that. Is [file in list] somehow a variable, or should I put somewhere in there?

Do you happen to know how to call gnuplot from Java? I've never called any external program.

Comment: @user2095534 No, you don't have to do anything with `[file in list]`: this iterates over the words (i.e. whitespace-separated strings) which are contained in the string variable `list` and stores it in the variable `file`. An example: `list="A.txt B.txt C.txt"; do for [file in list]{ print file }`. No, I don't know how to call gnuplot from Java.

Comment: Thanks a lot. That should do it. Appreciated